# Scene doesn't update javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

i'm making simple game in javafx. the problem i'm running into is when i try to control the rocket with up down right left buttons, it doesn't update the location of the rocket(lander.rocket()).The x,y cordinates of the rocket are alway zero and doesn't change. Please see the code.thanks

//Main class

```
Lander lander = new Lander();

Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane(), WIDTH, HEIGHT);


void Control_Rocket() {

   scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {

        switch (e.getCode()) {
            case RIGHT:
                lander.rocket().setTranslateX(lander.rocket().getTranslateX()+10);
                break;
            case LEFT:
                lander.rocket().setTranslateX(lander.rocket().getTranslateX()-10);
                break;
            case UP:
                lander.rocket().setTranslateY(lander.rocket().getTranslateY()-10);
                break;
            case DOWN:
                lander.rocket().setTranslateY(lander.rocket().getTranslateY()+10);
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("X:"+lander.rocket().getTranslateX()+" Y"+lander.rocket().getTranslateY());
    });

}

public Pane mainPane(){
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getChildren().add(Moon.background());
    pane.getChildren().addAll(Moon.hills());
    pane.getChildren().add(lander.rocket());
    return pane;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Control_Rocket();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Lunar-Lander!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

//Lander Class

```
public class Lander {

    double SPEED,UP_THRUST,GRAVITY,STEER_LEFT,STEER_RIGHT;

    private static final int _WIDTH = Main.WIDTH,
                             _HEIGHT = Main.HEIGHT;

    Rectangle rocket() {

        Rectangle rocket = new Rectangle(100,100, 10, 30);
        rocket.setFill(Color.RED);

        return rocket;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're changing one set of properties (`layoutX()` and `layoutY()`) but testing a completely different set of properties (`translateX()` and `translateY()`).

Comment: sorry updated the question now.still doesn't work

Comment: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Comment: @Sedrick thanks, but is very beginer level

Comment: Seems to be what you need. I suggest you go through it.

Comment: Your `rocket()` method creates a new rectangle each time you call it. So you create a new rectangle, change its `translateX` or `translateY` property, and then discard it. On the next key press, you create another new rectangle, etc. You need to put the rocket in a variable so you refer to the same rectangle every time.

Comment: @James_D hohoo its working mate. thanks really appreciate your effort